# std::bind - compiling unexpected (undeclared identifier) error in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, stdbind

Well another troubling error message for me, if I understand std::bind correctly I can arguments like `_1` to to the define a non-given argument? Right? Well considering the following line:

```
std::function<bool(value_type, const std::string &)> 
                             func(std::bind(&Pred, _1, "name"));
```

This should work, right? This would be used for a std::find_if() function, as such the first argument should be the value type & the second the string.

However visual studio 2010 complains about this with the following error message:

> error C2065: '_1' : undeclared identifier

That's just weird, how can I say in visual studio "hey the first argument isn't bound". Pred is a simple funciton taking `value_type, const std::string&` as arguments - returning a boolean.

Comment: `std::placeholders::_1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, you want this:

```
std::function<bool(value_type, const std::string &)> 
                         func(std::bind(&Pred, std::placeholders::_1, "name"));
```

Comment: hmm that actually made sense... en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind Put me on the wrong foot here :P

Comment: @paul23 yes, the page was not very clear about the placeholders being in a different namespace - I just edited the page to make that more obvious :-)